# Destroying Dialogs

Tags: jquery, dialog

I want to create a jQuery dialog from HTML returned by an AJAX call.  This works, but "destroying" the dialog doesn't remove the content from the div.  What is the best way to completely remove the content?

**Dialog creation code**

```
$.get( 'mysite/dialogcontent', null,
    function(data)
    {
        $(data).dialog( {
            buttons: { 'OK' : function() { $(this).dialog('destroy'); } }
        } );
    } );
```

**Possible solutions**

1. Manually find and remove the div
   after calling .dialog('destroy')?
2. Extend the destroy method and have
   my version simply remove the
   elements from the DOM?
3. Write a new method (kill?) that would do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think calling `remove()` on div that the dialog is created from should be the simplest one.

Comment: Hmm, that's actually simpler than I thought when I originally posted.  $(this).dialog('destroy').remove() did the trick.

Comment: Simple solutions make life nicer :]

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the div contents but leave the div itself?  `$(#mydiv).html("")` will empty it out.